# egit could not detect where git is installed

Tags: c++, eclipse

I installed "eclipse-cpp-juno-SR1-win32-x86_64" for my c++ programming. When I start eclipse, I got error of

1. egit could not detect where git is installed
2. "Varialbe of HOME" is not set on windows 8